# Sequence Diagrams

Tags: uml, diagrams

I recently read the book 'UML Distilled' and found the sequence diagrams very useful. My question is that can we show 'data flow' as well on a sequence diagram? This is my first time on sequence diagrams.

Nice to see some examples if any.

Comment: Sequence diagram is probably the most useful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: Sequence Diagram]
[UML: Sequence Diagram Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html)

The data is included as the parameters within the messages. For example the instance buyersBank of the Bank class takes an accountNumber and returns the balance for the buyersBank instance.

**Update:**

I have highlighed the key points from the [OMG specification.](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1.2/Superstructure/PDF) pg 491-494

- Asynchronous Messages have an open arrow head.
- (Default) Synchronous
  Messages typically represent
  operation calls and are shown with a
  filled arrow head  -The reply message
  from a method has a dashed line.
- Object creation Message has a dashed line with an open arrow.
- Lost
  Messages are described as a small
  black circle at the arrow end of the
  Message.
- Found Messages are
  described as a small black circle at
  the starting end of the Message.

```
<messageident> ::= 
([<attribute> ‘=’] <signal-or-operation-name>
[‘(‘ [<argument>[‘,’<argument>]* ‘)’]
[‘:’ <return-value>]) | ‘*’
```

**Examples of syntax:**

```
mymessage(14, - , 3.14, “hello”)  // second argument is undefined
v=mymsg(16, variab):96 // this is a reply message carrying the return value 96 assigning it to v
mymsg(myint=16)  // the input parameter ‘myint’ is given the argument value 16
```

**Where:**

```
v = attribute
mymessage = signal-or-operation-name
(16,vairab) = arguments
:96 = return value
```

**Note:**

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate will auto-generate sequence diagrams. You can reverse engineer existing methods by right-clicking and selecting auto-generate sequence diagram.

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Sequence Diagram]

[DevCurry](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/generate-sequence-diagrams-in-visual.html)

Comment: Greetings Donald, thanks for your answer, helped a lot. I finally drew my first sequence diagram for our small crawling engine. Anyway I have another question, how can I portray how a class assigns values to internal variables of another class on a sequence diagram?

Comment: One more thing, I got the chance to ask the same question to Fowler, the author of the book 'UML Distilled'. He said he has shown that in the newer edition of the book.